# How do i install ubuntu after download

Tags: boot

I downloaded ubuntu on my hp laptop currently having windows 7.I cannot open the iso files to launch the installation.How do I install the software

Comment: Ubuntu is not a "software" that you can install from Windows. It is a different OS.

Comment: Follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). You must have a USB flash drive and you will need to know how to boot a USB stick on your particular computer.

Comment: Technically you can install Ubuntu without a thumb-drive, but it's far more involved & just easier to write (or *burn*) the ISO to media such as thumb-drive (*it can be any media your hardware will boot too*) & boot from there.  Booting an ISO from an installed OS is much harder & if you don't have to do it, don't try (*I've only done it because I wanted to install onto a machine that didn't have working USB ports*)

Comment: If system is so old as to have Windows 7 originally, it is over 10 years old. Standard Ubuntu is probably too heavy weight. You may need a light weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie

Answer (score -1):

Win7 no longer receives security updates so is no safe to use - you need to migrate to win10/11 or just use linux/ubuntu. You have two options really.

1. Create a new partition on your hd using your win7 software for ubuntu (e.g. half the HD for each OS) and install ubuntu on the new partition.
2. Save your user data to something like a memory stick, wipe your hd completely and install Ubuntu on the whole HD. Then put your user data back into the ubuntu environment.

Either way, you need to burn the downloaded Ubuntu iso onto a free memory stick and install Ubuntu (on either the whole disk or the new partition) by powering down the pc and booting to the memory stick.  There is an auto installer that will take you through the process.  Google Ubuntu forum, there are many people and lots of information that goes through this in detail.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got a downvote. Is it only because quarkrad suggested to no longer use Windows 7? The rest of the answer is correct and provides some options. I think the most important thing to note here is that the iso file must be written as an image, not simply saved to a USB stick

Comment: I didn't vote either (no up/down), however my reactions are firstly to the off-topic upgrade windows (*sound advice for a windows user for sure, but I see it as off-topic on this site*), and then you '*glossed*' over the install process without any specific details or links.  I'm not sure you provided much '*concrete*' advice for the OP (*original poster*). I also wondered why you suggested Ubuntu Forums? as that may cause reaction that got downvote from users who try & help users on this site (like you don't appreciate people who assist others on askubuntu); I didn't think that was wise.

Comment: Some examples of links, verify ISO https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 create USB using ISO (ubuntu/macos/windows) https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview  how to install Ubuntu Desktop https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview though if wanted DVD https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1-overview etc.